# Vimeo Regex pattern

Tags: regex

can someone help me extract the following pattern in a Vimeo thumbnail URL:

"406/278/406278075" from:

"http://b.vimeocdn.com/ts/406/278/406278075_640.jpg"

I have tried creating my own regex for this but I can't get it.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(?:[0-9]+/?)+(?=_)`

```
(?:           = open non-capturing subpattern  
    [0-9]+    = digit, one or more times
    /?        = possibly followed by a forward slash
)             = close non-capturing pattern
+             = the preceding non-capturing subpattern, one or more times
(?=           = open look ahead assertion:
    _         = the pattern must be followed by an underscore
)             = close look ahead assertion
```

[*RegExr example*](http://regexr.com?33kmk)

With a tilde `~` as delimiters:

`~(?:[0-9]+/?)+(?=_)~`

Or, with a forward slash as delimiters:

`/(?:[0-9]+\/?)+(?=_)/`

Note: you have to escape the forward slash in the pattern then, this time.

Comment: Turns out I am getting the following error - Warning: preg_match(): Unknown modifier '?' - any ideas?

Comment: @xtiaan Since I used an unescaped forward slash in the pattern, you need to use different delimiters. A tilde `~` for instance. Or, if you want to keep using forward slashes as delimiters, escape the forward slash in the pattern like this: `\/`. See my edit, as well.

Answer (score 0):

Best easy and compatible thing i found. I'm not a RegExp expert.

`[0-9_]+(?!..jpg$)`

Then, it's the last value of the match array.